# Side scrolling game bullets are not appearing where I'm expecting

Tags: ios, swift, game-development

I'm using Xcode 13/Swift 5 to develop a side-scrolling game. The GameScene background is oversized but the game scene view is 1334x750. I have got the ship to move in all directions and when the ship reaches the edge of the oversized background, it loops to the other side (exit right enter left). When coding for shooting bullets (SpriteNode) I'm using the ship's location as the reference for where the bullet should fire from. However, I am experiencing some strange behaviors. When the ship is at location 0x0 the bullet fires from the same location and visually from the ship, however, when the ship is at 358x8 the bullet fires from this location but visually it is nowhere near the ship's location. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO Jonathan.
Please add some code, so users can help you.

Comment: Hi @Iskandir I have worked it out. I wasn’t adding the bullet to the scene, I had self.addChild(bulletNode) instead of scene.addChild(bulletNode).

Comment: Okay :) congrats and have fun on SO!